# Jquery Dialog Button click not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have a JQuery Dialog like this.

```
  <div id="dialog-form" title="TEST">
         <button id="button1" >BUTTON</button>
  </div>
```

My Init script for Dialog works fine and I can open dialog with this script

```
   .....
      $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 480,
            width: 780,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function () {
                $("#dialog-form").hide();
            }
        });
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    .....
```

But When am trying to get the click even of button with id `button1` am unable to get

```
     $(function () {
        $("#dialog-form").hide();
        $("#button1").click(function (e) {
            alert('clicked Button 1');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: where have you called this Init script for Dailog?

Comment: one some other button click.. and the dailog opens when i click it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click','#button1',function (e) {
    alert('clicked Button 1');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Not 100% sure if this is working, but because you are using the dialog-method, I think the dialog itself is created after the document is loaded and the function is executed.

Comment: Have tried this but no luck.. Went with using onclick of each button ..Any other ways will be helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: @user1042031: Ah, okey, my bad. If you resolved your problem, I recommend posting the answer yourself.

Comment: It is not exactly the anwser just a work around .. but still as I said am open for other anwsers aswell :)